# getErrorDialog is depreciated. What is the updated function, and how might I use it?

Tags: android

I am currently attempting to incorporate the use of Drive API authorisation into my app.

The Google Developers Guide states that I must use getErrorDialog in my Connection Failed method.

However, when I put the getErrorDialog in, it stated that the method was depreciated, and that I needed to use an 'updated' version.

It did not state, however, what I should use instead.

Does anyone know the updated version of this function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> However, when I put the getErrorDialog in, it stated that the method
>   was depreciated, and that I needed to use an 'updated' version.

`GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog` has been deprecated in favour of `GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog` , which is not a static method as it was for `GooglePlayServicesUtil`. You can get an instance of `GoogleApiAvailability` this way

```
GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
```

and call `getErrorDialog` on the returned instance

```
apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
```

where this is a `Context`'s object and `resultCode` is the return value of `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context)`. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Actually, what is it used for? If it is simply for an error dialogue, then I think I can just replace it with my custom Alert Dialog and not have to import anything.

Comment: it is a specific dialog from GooglePlayServices

Comment: So I can't just replace it? Does it do any other function other than notify the user on what error it is?

Comment: Iirc they return a meaningful message for the users, explaining what to do to fix the issue (if it is possible recover from it), so I will keep using it

Comment: Okay then. Cheer for the help!

Comment: What is the PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST and what should be the resultCode?